# Can't create transaction: internal error: Failed to get height

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, ledger, monerujo

I'm using

```
monero-gui-v0.15.0.2
Ledger Monero App 1.4.2
```

When I'm trying to do a send operation it fails with:

```
E result. THROW EXCEPTION: error::wallet_internal_error
E Can't create transaction:  internal error: Failed to get height
```

I have the same error with the monerujo app on Android:

```
monerujo 1.12.11
```

I have the same error when sending to own wallet. 
This means for the moment I'm not able to make a transaction from my wallet.

An idea what could be done to solve this?

Comment: This was resolved by selecting a different remote node. Strange I had the same error with Monero GUI and monerujo...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved by selecting a different remote node.